# The final result of my method not the result I want

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I hope that you are fine and doing well.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(reverse3(new int[] {1,2,3}));


    }

    public static int[ ] reverse3(int [] nums) {
        int [] j = new int[3];
        j[0] = nums[2];
        j[1] = nums[1];
        j[2] = nums[0];
        return j;
    }

}
```

As you see in the code the method is given an array of ints length 3, return a new array with the elements in reverse order, so {1, 2, 3} becomes {3, 2, 1}.

But when I click to run the final result is [I@7b23ec81
Can anyone tell me the solution and thanks.

Comment: Code, errors and results are expected to be provided as text on StackOverflow.

Comment: But I provide the code and the error in the photo

Comment: Yes, that is why I commented "Code, errors and results are expected to be provided **as text** on StackOverflow."

Comment: Okay how I can edit the question. Sorry I am new here

Comment: You can [edit] your question.

Comment: How about now ?

Comment: see my answer, you're actually printing the hascode for the returned array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are returning j which is an array object, you need to loop it out to print the values

In main function what you can do is:

```
 Array arr[] = reverse3(new int[]{1,2,3}); 
    for(int i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{ System.out.println(arr[i]); }
```

Comment: what is "Array" here

Answer (score 0):

I am doing well, thanks for asking, i hope you're doing good too

You are putting an array in the `println(array)`
println is not overloaded to print the array elements it prints the hascode for it if you pass the array.

**you need to do that**

```
for(int i : reverse(new int[]{1,2,5})
{
  System.out.print(i);
}
```

Comment: Thanks bro. Can I ask you another question ?

Comment: yes you can for sure, and consider upvoting the answer and tick it correct, if it worked for you

Comment: I have already tried to vote for the answers but a message pop up that said "Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score."

Comment: ok, if you are answered you should tick that right icon , so that others can see that question is answered

Comment: and about the question. When I put run the result is 321 and that is not what I want so I added "[" before the for loop and another one after it. The result now [321] then I added a comma like that System.out.print(j[i] + ","); but the final result now [3,2,1,] how I can remove the comma after number 1

Comment: thanks, feel free to ask more questions,and welcome to the stackoverflow ,you should also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The value you're getting is the address location of j at memory level.Its because j is the reference variable for your int[] object so obviously it gonna return reference of that object instead of the value on that particular location.
To achieve what you want you need to print the value of i using

`Code`

```
Array arr[] = reverse3(new int[]{1,2,3}); 
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++){
System.out.println("The value of arr[i] " +arr[i])
}
```